# Finding the Amp hour of battery

Tags: batteries

I have a 12 volt Ni Cad Screwdriver battery (to be exact, it is a Black & Decker Firestorm)  I would like to find the amp-hours of the battery. The battery doesn't say anything on it (except that it is 12 volts), and I couldn't find any info online. I have no amp meter for testing amps drawn/time, but I tested a 12 volt 21/5 watt bulb and it lasted around 45 minutes. I did the division of (21/5)/12 and got .35 amp hours if it lasted an hour, but it was only 45 minutes and that would be less than .3 amp hours. I don't think this is true. So am I doing anything wrong and if so, what should I fix, and how can I find the amp hours?

edit:  The model number of the pack is ps160 12v type 3 power pack

edit 2: I just figured out that the 21/5 means there is 2 filaments and doesn't mean "21 divided by 2" so I probably used the 21 watt because I used the brighter one.

Comment: Working backwards through your math, you had 0.35Ah with a 1 hour discharge, suggesting 4.2W.  This is neither the 21W filament, nor the 5W filament.  Which filament did you use in your discharge test?

Comment: oh I thought it 21 divided by 5! silly me!!

Comment: I used the brighter one, which was probably the 21 watt

Comment: Bingo.  21W, 12V, 45min = 1.31Ah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Black & Decker Firestorm 12 Volt drill / screwdriver FS1202D seems to match your description, I have the same product. This model uses a [12 Volt NiCd 1.2 Ampere-hour](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0008ELOU8) battery pack.

If your experiments indicate a much lower ampere-hour rating, that could be due to battery aging, charging issues or the battery being loaded beyond the current / continuous operation parameters it is rated for.

If you could provide the screwdriver model number, a more definitive answer could be obtained.

Comment: +1. Good bit of detective work, and 1.2Ah matches nicely with the rough calculation in comments for the 21W bulb.